# prevent rounding number in expanding data

Tags: r

I have a large data frame named df with 1481581 observations. what I want to do is expand my data frame based on weight variable. my actual number of observation after expanding should be 75149669, but when I  expand data some observations are omitted because of rounding weight values . my question is how can I expand my data without any rounding.
any help would be appreciated.

```
 district residence gender age  weight  Id
1         00         3      2  23 49.4216   1
2         00         3      1  44 49.4216   2
3         00         3      1  71 49.4216   3
4         00         3      1  33 49.4216   4
5         00         3      1  18 49.4216   5
6         00         3      1  51 49.4216   6
7         00         3      1  65 49.4216   7
8         00         3      1  24 49.4216   8
9         00         3      1  41 49.4216   9
10        00         3      2   7 49.4216  10
11        00         3      1  53 49.4216  11
12        00         3      2  12 49.4216  12
13        00         3      1  14 49.4216  13
14        00         3      2  35 49.4216  14
15        00         3      2  12 49.4216  15
16        00         3      2  21 49.4216  16
17        00         3      1  17 49.4216  17
18        00         3      2  37 49.4216  18
19        00         3      2  71 49.4216  19

df1 <- df [rep(1:nrow(df), df$weight),]
```

Comment: Maybe you want using `ceiling`: `df[rep(1:nrow(df), ceiling(df$weight)),]`

Comment: How do you expand a row with weight 49.4216 if you don't round it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to repeat a row 49.4216 times, so you can either deal with this by rounding the weights in such a way that the total sum is preserved, with something like:

```
c.weights <- round(cumsum(df$weight), 0) #cumulative weights, rounded
i.weights <- c(c.weights[1], diff(c.weights))  #weight for each row as integer
df1 <- df [rep(1:nrow(df), i.weights),]
```

So some of the rows with weight 49.4216 would be repeated 49 times, and some 50 times to preserve the total weight. It does this by using the cumulative sum of weights down the column (c.weights) and rounds this to the nearest whole number. The number of repeats of a row is the difference in the cumulative sum.

or alternatively, you can sample at random using your weights as sample weights with something like

```
set.seed(0)
df1 <- df[sample(nrow(df), sum(df$weight) replace=TRUE, prob=df$weight)),]
```

due to random sampling the rows might appear more or less than expected, but the (mathematically) expected number of copies of the row would match the weights.

Comment: thank you so much. can you explain more about c.weights and i weights?

Comment: Hopefully the updates help you understand this better

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
df1 <- df [rep(1:nrow(df), ceiling(df$weight)),]
```

Comment: it works but my data would be greater than 75149669!

Comment: You have to explain by what rule do you want to approximate your weights since the `times` argument of `rep` should be an integer. Trying different decimal numbers suggests that the function approximates `times` with `floor`, that is, with the smallest integer. With `ceiling` the weights are approximated to the largest integers